# Why does this Rails transaction fail to lock?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

Why can't I lock this record?

```
  User.transaction do
    p current_user.inspect
    p "************"
    user = current_user.lock!
    p "************"
```

#### Log

```
"#<User id: 1, username: ...
"************"
PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:294:in `block in withdrawBTC'
```

#### Console

I can lock it from the console.

```
irb(main):021:0> User.transaction do
irb(main):022:1* u.lock!
irb(main):023:1> end
```

#### Version

Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange, I restarted the server, and it got past that line. I don't know why, since it was in development mode. Rails, you so flaky!

Comment: I've seen this type of error before, in a different context. In a Java daemon I wrote, if I had (for example) a syntax error in one query, all other queries after that, no matter what kind, would be rejected with this error. I then have to stop and restart the daemon to get past it. Is it possible you had something like that as well at one point; did something crap out before you got to this locking part?

Comment: Yes something SQL related did crap out. I was intentionally causing an error to test a test case, then took it out.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it probably wasn't Rail's fault, though Rails is indeed bizarre and flakey.

This part of the output:

```
ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

says that a *previous command in the same transaction failed* and your program (or Rails) ignored the error and tried to continue. That won't work - subsequent commands will just fail until the transaction is rolled back.